# bibliography: problem with counting entries

Tags: bibtex, natbib

I have a problem with my bibliography. I use natbib.

I have literatur from the same author in the same year.

I have a own Function "DateWithBrackets", see below.

And my bibliography looks like this:

```
author, (2013)a,...

author, (2013)b,...
```

but it should looks like this

```
author, (2013a),...

author, (2013b),...
```

this is the function I use:

```
FUNCTION {format.dateWithBrackets}
{ year duplicate$ empty$
    { "empty year in " cite$ * warning$
       pop$ "" }
    'skip$
  if$
  month empty$
    'skip$
    { month
      " " * swap$ *
    }
  if$                                   
  duplicate$ empty$ 'skip$              %% added
  { "(" swap$ * ")" *}                  %% added
  if$
  extra.label *
}
```

Comment: I found a solution with: if$ extra.label * ")" *

Answer (score 1):

OP's code, moved from the question and marked there as a solution:

```
FUNCTION {format.dateWithBrackets}
{ year duplicate$ empty$
    { "empty year in " cite$ * warning$
       pop$ "" }
    'skip$
  if$
  month empty$
    'skip$
    { month
      " " * swap$ *
    }
  if$                                   
  duplicate$ empty$ 'skip$              %% added
  { "(" swap$ * }                  %% added
  if$
  extra.label * ")" *
}
```